# Unable to award bounty because moderators put question on hold

Tags: support, bounty, on-hold

My question

- [YouTube tag doesn't seem to have any effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25198515/youtube-tag-doesnt-seem-to-have-any-effect)

has received excellent answers and I would be glad to award the bounty to one of the answers, but your moderators don't like my question so they've put it on hold, which seems to prevent me from awarding the bounty.

Comment: The question is inappropriate for SO, and was closed for that reason. If your question is off-topic, it doesn't belong on SO and therefore there's no value to any of the answers (at SO). Consider yourself lucky that you received any answers at all to an off-topic question. (And check the site guidelines before posting any additional questions at SO.)

Comment: Also, 272 questions with 475 reputation?!?! How do you do that?

Comment: The SO post is clearly off-topic and deserves to be not only closed but deleted.  But this post is on-topic as it is asking about the rules of SO.  Thus, I cannot vote to close this question.

Answer (score 11):

Off-topic posts should not be present, much less have bounties.

As far as having "received excellent answers," none of the answers have a positive score.

Your bounty was returned to you by a moderator, so at least you didn't lose the 50 points that you offered.

The question is already closed and is close to being deleted.  If that happens, you'll get even more reputation returned to you, as the 19 downvotes on the question will be rescinded.  Consider that a gift.

Please take the time to learn about what questions are accepted on this site.  You rarely get positive score for any question, and that's a problem.